# Java: Invoke a method with an variable length argument lists with an ArrayList with arbitrary length

Tags: java, arraylist

i got a function with the following signature

```
foo(Object...){}
```

And i got an ArrayList "list"

How can i invoke the function with an ArrayList of arbitrary length. i mean how can i avoid this

```
if(list.size == 1){
    foo(list.get(0))
}else if(list.size == 2){
    foo(list.get(0),list.get(1))
}
```

Comment: Am I to understand from the second block of code that you overloaded foo() with multiple methods, each one taking a different number of arguments? And then you have one varargs method also? That you then call out to the correct overloaded method with? Why not just loop through the objects in the varargs method instead, and perform whatever action is necessary in the loop?

Answer (score 2):

You can call `toArray()` on your `ArrayList` to pass an array to your varargs method `foo`.

```
foo(list.toArray());
```

Comment: Indeed, or even better: `foo(list.toArray(new ArrayList<>(list.size())));`

Comment: @MenoHochschild Sure, that also works, but because the `foo` method takes `Object...` it'll work either way.